# is it possible to stop hiding the UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a need to stop the `UINavigationBar` from hiding when I scroll a `UITableView`
I have tried the following, but it just does not seem to work:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear {    
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is hiding when you scroll, that is presumably because you configured the navigation controller's `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property. So don't do that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/hidesBarsOnSwipe

Comment: I just tried doing a search for hidesBarsOnSwipe in my project and it's not in there at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can opt-out of this option in Storyboard:

In the Document's Outline sidebar select the Scene you wish to alter [this will be the one with the Navigation Bar tab in it]:

[image: pic1]

Now in your Utilities sidebar, in the attributes tab you will see all the options for the navigation bar, select/de-select all that apply to you, in your case "Hide Bars on Swipe" :

[image: pic2]

Comment: I'm not using storyboard I'm afraid. My project is completely programatic